# PHASER : Load and add image in create()?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, facebook-instant-games

i’m trying to load and add images in create().
It seems that I need to start the new load, so my code is :

```js
    this.load.image('sky', 'ASSETS/IMAGES/from_phaser/space3.png');
    this.load.start();
    this.add.image(width/2, height/2, 'sky');
```

As I can see in Chrome’s inspector, the load worked, but the image isn’t displayed…
Why `this.add.image(width/2, height/2, ‘sky’);` doesn’t display anything or at least throw an error ?

Comment: Assets have to be loaded in the `preload()` predefined method

Answer (score 0):

You will want to load all your images in the preload function. This function is called by Phaser at its start. You will want to preload all your assets, to use them later of different manners. Once it has been preloaded, you can add it to your default scene in the create function.

```js
function preload () {
    this.load.image('sky', 'ASSETS/IMAGES/from_phaser/space3.png');
}

function create () {
    this.add.image(width/2, height/2, 'sky');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* load assets at any point, including in `create`, the process is async. So you need to wait for the file complete event before you can use that asset. It's definitely not available by the next line of the code.

There are several events you could use, the easiest is probably `this.load.on('complete')`. But, you can also listen for `filecomplete` to learn when a single file has loaded.